# How to load jQuery in modal bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

So I have this code that work well to load 10 extra "article" after click on button that work fin in my page.

```
$(function(){
    $(".trick-show").slice(0, 10).css('display', 'flex'); // select the first ten
    $("#loadMore").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".trick-show:hidden").slice(0, 5).css('display', 'flex'); // select next 5 hidden tricks and show them
        if($(".trick-show:hidden").length === 0){ // check if any hidden tricks still exist
            $("#loadMore").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Add disabled on button after the last trick is shown
            alert("It was your last load ! No more tricks to show..."); // alert if there are none left
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is that when I use the same jQuery code in bootstrap 4 modal. It is changing well the first article display, but it does not do anything when click on button. I was thinking to add a setTimeout or use a show.bs.modal but I dont know exactly where.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JQuery .on() method

```
$(document).on("click", "#loadMore", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
        $(".trick-show:hidden").slice(0, 5).css('display', 'flex'); // select next 5 hidden tricks and show them
        if($(".trick-show:hidden").length === 0){ // check if any hidden tricks still exist
            $("#loadMore").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Add disabled on button after the last trick is shown
            alert("It was your last load ! No more tricks to show..."); // alert if there are none left
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Gökten Karadağ,

That is working perfectly after changing this small error :
On 2nd line instead of "e.preventDefault();", Change for "event.preventDefault();. because this is the name you used in function.
Thank you very much for your help